# Definition of 'depauperise'

Tags: meaning, etymology

What is the definition of 'depauperise' (or 'depauperize')? Does it mean "to make someone poor", or "to rescue someone from poverty" (de- +‎ pauperize)? Has its meaning changed over time? What is its etymology?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul - That link gives both definitions.

Comment: Collins Dictionary gives the two seemingly opposite meanings above; Chambers 20th Century Dictionary gives `Depauperise - to remove from the state of paupers` and_`Depauperate, to impoverish`. These words are not in common use.

Comment: @HotLicks - what link?

Comment: The existence of the two opposite senses stems from the prefix *de-* having two roughly opposite senses. The more common meaning of the prefix favours interpreting the word to mean remove from poverty, but the analogy with the biological term (adjective) *depauperate* favours interpreting it to mean impoverish. Given that the word is very rarely used in either sense, it is impossible to say which sense is the dominant one.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - The link DS deleted.

Comment: This is dictionary stuff.

Comment: And yet @billj none of my dictionaries give me proper info., history etc. regarding the opposing meanings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to have been used with opposite meanings as far back as Google can remember.

> What is wanted is to *depauperize the country*, as quickly as possible, forthwith. The advantages of the proposed system are two-fold.  One consists in providing cheap and healthy support for the destitute.

[The Present Poverty of Ireland Convertible Into the Means of Her Improvement, Under a Well-administered Poor Law (1838)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Present_Poverty_of_Ireland_Convertib/T50uAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22depauperize%22&pg=PA147&printsec=frontcover)

> ...and Sir Edward Coke conceives it [usury] was meant to be taken of strangers only, as a mean to exterminate or depauperize them, so as they should not be enabled to invade or injure God's people.

[A Summary of the History and Law of Usury (1835)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Summary_of_the_History_and_Law_of_Usur/TTdfAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22depauperize%22&pg=PA3&printsec=frontcover)

It seems reasonable to suspect that this discrepancy was caused by some confusion, or some different opinions on whether *depauperize* should mean *to make depauperate*, or *to un-pauperize*.

> **pauperize** verb
>
> : to reduce to poverty
>
> ...
>
> First Known Use of *pauperize*
> 1806, in the meaning defined above

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pauperize

> **depauperate** adjective
>
> 1 : falling short of natural development or size
>
> 2 : impoverished
> a *depauperate* fauna
>
> ...
>
> First Known Use of *depauperate*
> 15th century, in the meaning defined at sense 1

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/depauperate

Comment: Thanks for the info.! Probably the best we can get for now, although more research by etymologists would be appreciated.